# VSCode のプラグインを日本語化したい

Tags: vscode

VSCodeで開発しているのですが、Dockerプラグインなどのプラグインは日本語化することが出来ませんでした。
Dockerのコードにカーソルを合わせると英文で説明が出てきますので、日本語だとすごく使いやすく勉強になるなと思っているのですが、そもそもプラグインなどは日本語化する事は出来ないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

まず、VSCode の拡張機能は VSCode が公式でメンテンナンスしているものもあればユーザーが作っているものもあり、事情が拡張機能ごとに異なります。

その上で、「日本語化できるか」という質問には「その拡張機能が対応していれば」という答えになります。各々の拡張機能がローカライズされているかを確認してください。

いくつかの拡張機能では、Display Language を設定することによって表示を日本語にすることができます。コマンドパレットから "Configure Display Language" を選び、`ja` を選択してください。選択できない場合、"Install additional languages..." から日本語を探してください。日本語 UI を提供するための Language Pack が拡張機能として提供されています: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-CEINTL.vscode-language-pack-ja

より詳しくは VSCode のドキュメントをご覧ください: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales